# How to monitor IObservable<double> for Out of Range for Extended Period of Time

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an `IObservable<double>` that gives values read from a sensor at a somewhat regular interval. I want to signal when the value of the sensor is out of bounds for an extended period of time.

As a concrete example, imagine the observable is of a temperature sensor. I want to monitor for when the temperature exceeds 100°C for 5 seconds. That is, from the `IObservable<double>` produce an observable or event that fires once when the temperature has exceeded 100°C for 5 seconds. If the temperature reads above 100°C for any number of samples for less than 5 seconds, this has no effect. 5 seconds after the first of a set of samples all above 100°C it should raise a signal. If the value continues to be above 100°C the signal should not be reraised until the temperature drops below 100°C and then again exceeds it for 5 seconds.

It seems like this should be straightforward to do with reactive extensions, but being new to it, I'm not able to find anything. I've looked through http://reactivex.io and http://introtorx.com but not found anything. I may just not know the correct term to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought about this a bit, and realized that we may be overthinking it.

Let's start with an observable threshold:

```
var threshold = 
source
.Select(temp => temp > 100)
.DistinctUntilChanged();
```

This produces a value when there's a *change* to above 100, or below it. If it *continues* to be above 100, or stays below it, it does not produce any new values.

Now let's define:

```
var alarmUp =
    threshold
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .Where(cond => cond == true);
```

Here, if the condition doesn't change for 5 seconds, the `throttle` operator spits out a value. Now it could be `true` (> 100) for 5 seconds, or `false` (< 100).
We are only interested in it being `true` (> 100).

In between, if there are any changes, the throttle operator gets reset, so the condition must hold for at least 5 seconds.

Comment: Great answer. Some info about the [`Throttle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229400(v%3Dvs.103)) operator I just learned: *Ignores elements from an observable sequence which are followed by another element within a specified relative time duration.* Known as [`Debounce`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) in the ReactiveX vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.Switch()` for situations whenever a new value coming in makes you want to ignore the results of any previous values that came in.

Here's the query you need:

```
IObservable<Unit> query =
    source
        .Select(x => x > 100.0)
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Select(x => x
            ? Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)).Select(x => Unit.Default)
            : Observable.Never<Unit>())
        .Switch();
```

The `.Select(x => x >= 100.0).DistinctUntilChanged()` combination changes the source to a `IObservable<bool>` that only fires when the sensor **flips** between `x > 100.0` and `x <= 100.0` - `true` for exceeded 100°C and false for 100°C or less.

Now we turn the `IObservable<bool>` into an `IObservable<IObservable<Unit>>`. This is an observable that produces other observables. When we receive in a `true` I want to return an `IObservable<Unit>` that fires after `5.0` seconds, and when we receive a `false` I want to return an observable that doesn't return a value at all.

That's what `.Select(x => x ? Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)).Select(x => Unit.Default) : Observable.Never<Unit>())` does.

Finally we pop in the `.Switch()` which changes the `IObservable<IObservable<Unit>>` into `IObservable<Unit>` by only producing values based on the last inner `IObservable<Unit>` produced. In other words, if the sensor flips from above `100.0` to below again in under `5.0` seconds then it ignores the value of the `Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))` and is waiting for a value from `Observable.Never<Unit>()`. If it exceeds `100.0` for over `5.0` then the `Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))` fires an you get a `Unit` produced from your query.

This behaves exactly as you wanted.

Here's a slightly simpler version of the query:

```
IObservable<Unit> query =
    source
        .Select(x => x > 100.0)
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Select(x => x
            ? Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
            : Observable.Never<long>())
        .Switch()
        .Select(x => Unit.Default);
```

Comment: Upvoted. This is the kind of solution I originally tried to write, but failed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do it by using the built-in operators (functional style), but it is more straitforward to do it by implementing a custom operator with imperative logic.

```
public static IObservable<Unit> Alarm<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
    T threshold, TimeSpan delay, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
    return Observable.Create<Unit>(o =>
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        int alarmState = 0; // 0: OK, 1: above threshold, 2: signal transmitted

        return source.Subscribe(x =>
        {
            if (comparer.Compare(x, threshold) >= 0)
            {
                if (alarmState == 0)
                {
                    alarmState = 1;
                    stopwatch.Restart();
                }
                else if (alarmState == 1 && stopwatch.Elapsed >= delay)
                {
                    alarmState = 2;
                    o.OnNext(Unit.Default);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alarmState = 0;
            }
        }, o.OnError, o.OnCompleted);
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the OP requested. If the source observable only produces a single value above `100` then this operator doesn't fire after `5.0` seconds. In fact, it would never fire. An answer requires a `5.0` second timer of some sort to work as the OP requested.

Comment: @Enigmativity this is indeed a flaw in my solution, and thanks for pointing it out. I didn't mention it because the OP specified that the sensor is expected to produce values at a somewhat regular interval. In any case [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59815144/11178549) is much better than mine, and should be preferred.

Comment: Thank you. In this case I actually like the `Throttle` solution better. `Switch` is just more powerful and can be used for more scenarios that `Throttle`, so it is good to learn.